# Search and replace words in a word document C#

Tags: search, checkbox, replace, ms-word

I want to make a program which i have to load a word document and then check a `checkbox` for searching and replacing words, then click a button which then searches and replaces it

I know the code is:

```
private void SearchReplace()
{
    Word.Find findObject = Application.Selection.Find;
    findObject.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Text = "find me";
    findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Replacement.Text = "Found";

object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref  missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

How can i put this into a `checkbox`?

Comment: Do you have a windows form? What kins of Visual Studio application do you use? In case of a winform you should create a form and execute the method above on button click. Do you need more help?

Comment: i use Visual Studio 2013. http://gyazo.com/8bf788999b5be23fef5d6bb4098c4449

i want to make it so that when i check the first checkbox and then click "Protect" it will for example change spaces to another character in the word document

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the `Protect` button, its method will be opened. In it you can place any code you would like.

First check if the checkbox is checked and then the code of replacing spaces :

```
 if (checkboxName.Checked == true)
   {
     SearchReplace();
   }
```